# Why does the site think my question is subjective?

Tags: support, title, subjective

I recently asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169107/do-zombie-bites-in-the-resident-evil-games-turn-you-into-a-zombie) on the scifi stack exchange.

After I typed the question, I got a blurb that said "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed." I'm honestly curious why I got that. There's not a doubt in my mind that this is an objective yes/no answer and I have no reason to believe it will be closed.

I tried a couple rewrites of the question and I kept getting the blurb, so I figure this is just bad parsing on the site's part, but I'm still curious why I got it.

Of course, if I'm misunderstanding things and did post an off-topic question, please let me know and I'll delete it. But I'd still like an explanation as to why.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you included the word 'you'.

Any title with the words *you, your, best, favorite/favourite, worst*, and *hardest* get this warning. It's kind of outdated; see [What algorithm does Stack Exchange use to determine if a question may be subjective?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/what-algorithm-does-stack-exchange-use-to-determine-if-a-question-may-be-subject/20014#20014) on Meta.SE.

Comment: This problem has come up before on various SE sites. Really "you" and "your" should be removed from the list.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - it probably is a good heuristic for StackOverflow :)